# Failure to load iOS core data database first time

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-data

In my iOS app, my database is in the folder of `Application support/myDatabase` folder.  Hare are codes to get this folder created if not exist:

```
class MyDatabaseURLHelper {
  private databaseBase: URL {
    let baseDir: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory = 
      .applicationSupportDirectory
    let subDir = "myDatabase"
    var url = FileManager.default.urls(
      for: baseDir,
      in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendPathComponent(subDir)
    return url
  }

  func databaseURL() -> URL? {
    var url: URL? = databaseBase
    let dbName = "MyDatabaseFile"
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) { 
      do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(
          atPath: databaseBase.path, 
          withIntermediateDirectories: true, 
          attributes: nil)
      } catch {
        url = nil
    }
    return url?.appendPathComponent(dbName)
  }
}
```

I have tested above codes. The database sub folder is created if no exist(first time), and the database url looks fine.

Here is a snip of my codes to load database:

```
let modelName = "MyDatabase"
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelName)
let url = MyDatabaseURLHelper().databaseURL()!
let storeDesription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
storeDesription.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
storeDesription.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDesription]
container.loadPersistentStores() {
  (storeDescription, error) in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
      let msg = "Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)"
      fatalError(msg) // <- I got exception here! if database file does not exist first time.
    }
}
return container // No errors if database exists
```

My app runs OK for existing users since they have db file. However, for new users, I got my app crashes. New users don't have database at their first time run. I verified the same result in my Xcode simulators.

The following is error message:

```
*"Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 \"The file “MyDatabase” couldn’t be opened.\" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/.../Application/8DBC6D4F-967C-433D-9B28-60451CDAECDB/Library/Application Support/myDatabase, \"NSSQLiteErrorDomain\": 14]"*
```

Not sure what has been changed in recent iOS (15.4). What's missing in loading persistence store?

Comment: Actually, the codes in my question are correct. In my real project, the more complicated codes, I made mistakes not adding database name to URL. If you look at my error message carefully, the database name is not in URL: "MyDatabaseFile" not at the end. Anyway, the simplified codes are working fine,

Comment: Why do you *reinvent the wheel*? Core Data does all the work on your behalf to create the database files by default.

Comment: Did you try to create first the application support directory as it does not exist by default.

Comment: @PtitXav the "Application support" is always there as you can see in code. What I like is to create a sub-folder exclusively for my app's database files so that it would not mess up with other files by Apple or my app (I may add more files in the future). I save my database name somewhere and retrieve the name for future startup, but first-time user would not able to get the db file name at all. That's why only first-time user experience crash issue. Now I fixed the issue. First time use will use a default name if app cannot find it, and save the name after it is created.